# Twilio webhook sending %00 instead of @ symbol

Tags: twilio, webhooks

I'm using twilio webhook to process text messages, when message body contains @ symbol twilio sends %00 instead. Example:
Body=%00%00%00%00

Is there a way to get actual data?

Comment: Twilio developer evangelist here. I just tested this myself and receieved the "@" symbol correctly. What are you using to parse your incoming webhooks? I tested using http://twimlbin.com/ which shows you your incoming requests.

Comment: I've used ngrok and it shows Body=%00%00%00%00. I'm using android kitkat to send text.

Comment: I've checked twimlbin and it's a same. Looks like @ symbol doesn't come properly from android.

Comment: It is probably worth sending this issue to help@twilio.com who will be able to look into deeper than I can right now. Sorry I couldn't solve your issue myself.